# Passing a @selector dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, selector

Depending on the result from ABPersonGetSortOrdering(), I want to sort a UILocalizedIndexCollation by first name or last name.

I'm having problems switching the @selector used for the collationStringSelector parameter.

It'd be very easy to just write this verbosely:

```
NSArray *sortedSubarray;
if (ABPersonGetSortOrdering() == 0) {
    sortedSubarray = [collation sortedArrayFromArray:[sections objectAtIndex:section] collationStringSelector:@selector(fname)];
} else {
    sortedSubarray = [collation sortedArrayFromArray:[sections objectAtIndex:section] collationStringSelector:@selector(lname)];
}
```

I've tried something like this with no luck:

```
SEL sorter = ABPersonGetSortOrdering() == 0 ? NSSelectorFromString(@"fname") : NSSelectorFromString(@"lname");
sortedSubarray = [collation sortedArrayFromArray:[sections objectAtIndex:section] collationStringSelector:@selector(sorter)];
```

I've tried out other ideas as well, and nothing seems to be working.

Is there a better way to pass a selector name dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there, just remove the `@selector()` part from around `sorter`:

```
sortedSubarray = [collation sortedArrayFromArray:[sections objectAtIndex:section] collationStringSelector:sorter];
```

Comment: awesome!  I was trying my hardest not to ask the question...at least I was close though!  Thanks for the quick reply.